# Stored Procedure for reference table data matching and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I have 2 tables here.

```
shades_table
color_name category location
Aqua       Blue      House A
Denim      Blue      House B
Azure      Blue      House B
Zaffre     Blue      House A
Scarlet    Red       House C
Ruby       Red       House D
Chili      Red       House D
Crimson    Red       House A

objects_table
object_name       color_cat    location2
Super Aqua shoes      Null      Null
Azure wallet          Null      Null
Awesome Scarlet chair Null      Null
Ruby socks            Null      Null
Sparkly Denim chalk   Null      Null
Chili paper           Null      Null
Zaffre vase           Null      Null
Sharp Crimson eraser  Null      Null
Crimson watch         Null      Null
Excellent Scarlet bucket  Null
```

I have a reference table called shades_table. A column contains color_name, and the other column contains the category of the color.

I am working on the objects_table. The object_name column contains the color name. I would want a procedure/program to automatically match the color_names to the Object_name, and then update the Null values in the color_cat column.

My current method is to export the shades_table to a csv file. Then I wrote a Java program which reads the csv file, and output to a sql file to be run by the server:

```
UPDATE objects_table SET color_cat='Blue', location2 = 'House A' WHERE object_name LIKE '%Aqua%' AND color_cat IS NULL
UPDATE objects_table SET color_cat='Blue', location2 = 'House B' WHERE object_name LIKE '%Denim%' AND color_cat IS NULL
UPDATE objects_table SET color_cat='Blue', location2 = 'House B' WHERE object_name LIKE '%Azure%' AND color_cat IS NULL
etc...
```

This method works, but it's stupid, cumbersome.
I just don't know how to write the SQL statements which can do what I want.

Update:
I have added an extra column which I also want to match.(Refer to my Java program output). UPDATE statement with 2 SET doesn't work.
example

```
update o
set o.color_cat = s.category,
set o.location2 = s.location
...
```

doesn't work,
gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

Comment: ok, I didn't know the correct syntax should be update a
set a.color_cat = b.category,
a.location2 = b.location .... I shouldn't type SET the 2nd time. Thanks, Unnikrishnan R, you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update query.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.color_cat=b.category
FROM objects_table a
JOIN shades_table b ON a.[object_name] LIKE '%'+b.[color_name]+'%' 
WHERE a.color_cat IS null
```

If you want it as a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Updateobjectstable
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE a
    SET a.color_cat=b.category
  FROM objects_table a
         JOIN shades_table b ON a.[object_name] LIKE '%'+b.[color_name]+'%' 
  WHERE a.color_cat IS null
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use procedure for this task. Plain SQL should work.

```
UPDATE objects_table ot
SET color_cat = st.category
FROM shades_table st 
WHERE ot.object_name ILIKE concat('%', st.color_name, '%')
  AND ot.color_cat IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `update` statement will do that for you:

```
update o
set o.color_cat = s.category
from objects_table o
    left join shades_table s
        on(o.[object_name] like '%' + s.color_name + '%')
```